# K&R hash function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

The part of following code is an implementation of a simple hash lookup algorithm from K&R.
*lookup* searches for s in the table, and returns a pointer to the place where it was found, or NULL if it wasn't there:

```
struct hashElement *lookup(char *name){
    struct hashElement *currentStruct;
    int cmp;
    for (currentStruct = hashTable[calcIndex(name)]; currentStruct; currentStruct = currentStruct->p)
    if (cmp = strcmp(name, currentStruct->name) == 0)
        return currentStruct;
    return NULL;}
```

*Install* uses *lookup* to determine whether the name being installed is already present:

```
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL){
    np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
    ...}
...}
```

If *lookup* returns NULL, it means that there is no *name* installed in hash table, and I should allocate memory for new element which type will be nlist.

But, based on this  `np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));` *np will allocate memory for NULL if *lookup* return NULL.
Shouldn't I always allocate memory size for nlist instead of *np?

Comment: Why don't you see what you get by printing `sizeof(*np)`? Maybe that will give some idea as to which element you are actually allocating space for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **np will allocate memory for NULL if lookup return NULL.*

Nope, that is not true.

First of all, in

```
  np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
```

[the cast in not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917). That said

```
 np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
```

is the same as

```
np = malloc(sizeof(struct nlist));
```

as the type of `*np` is `struct nlist`. Remember, `sizeof` operator does not evaluate it's operand unless it's a VLA.

to quote `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.